# Query regarding .dts file

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am reading about .dts from Linux Source and have a query regarding Device register space.
Following content took from "arch/arm/boot/dts/omap3.dtsi"

```
   dss@48050000 {

            compatible = "ti,omap3-dss","simple-bus";  
            reg = <0x48050000 0x200>;
            ti,hwmods = "dss_core";
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            ranges;

                 dispc@48050400 {

                           compatible = "ti,omap3-dispc";
                            reg = <0x48050400 0x400>;
                            interrupts = <25>;
                           ti,hwmods = "dss_dispc";
                                };
                  }
```

For the node  dss@48050000 device's register starts from 0x48050000 with size of 0x200 .
My doubt is for child node dispc@48050400 the base address should starts from 0x48050200 since earlier device register address ends at 0x48050200.

How come it is starting from 0x48050400 .

Also what's difference between dts and dtsi file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at page 2438 the omap3 TR (SPRUF98X–April 2010–Revised June 2012)
http://www.ti.com/product/omap3530

You can see that the register map shows the display subsystem registers start at 0x48050000 (which correlates to the dts file). It also shows a big gap in the register addresses, with DISPC_REVISION at 0x48050400, which also correlates with the dts file.

I suppose you could make the size of the registers at 0x48050000 0x10 (because that is the size of the register space at that address), or you could make it 0x400 just so it goes to the start of the next block even though most of that space is unused. Whatever the case, it doesn't really matter much so long as all registers are covered.

So the moral of the story is that the software has to conform to the hardware, and that is why there is a gap.

Also a dtsi file is just a dst include file... a dtsi can be included in multiple dts files.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the clarification ,So your point is ,It is normal to have this gap in address space of two register ,I was thinking registers belongs to same device are at consecutive memory location.

Comment: It is totally up to the hardware designers, those guys can do whatever they want... even waste address space as they did in this case. :D In reality there may be a technical reason for it, such as undocumented registers, or maybe plans for version 2.0 where they fill in the gap with new registers...

Comment: Fine @Chris ,I got your point.One final thing would like to know,is it safe to use these address to write/read register from user-space??

Comment: I would say it is pretty unsafe to do I/O to these address spaces, the address space is undefined, so who knows what side affects I/O will have.

Comment: Ok chris But I am into a situation where my kernel does not provide any sysfs implementation to access some register defined in dts file,So only left with me is write/read these register from user-space.Would you like to comments anything on it.

Comment: Consider using dd and /dev/mem, or compile a new kernel with the sysfs features you need (if it exists), or write your own device driver.

Comment: When you were asking "One final thing would like to know,is it safe to use these address to write/read register from user-space" I assumed you were talking about the gaps in the registers... was that correct?

Comment: Thanks Chris ,got your two points of using dd and /dev/mem but how Do i check if required sysfs feature is there or not(for accessing particular device).We have to access CPSW_STAT_PORT_EN register which is on TI's Keystone board.How do I check its sysfs support is there on not

Comment: I assumed you were talking about the gaps in the registers... was that correct?  Sorry for that .May be I was taking this discussion to other point,Yes it was regarding gaps in address space because say ,if I want to access 3rd register from the base address then if gap is there then as per logic I can't get the right address,My logic is based on fact that register are consecutive.

Comment: Well, your logic should be based on the hardware register layout, as that is the only thing that will work.